# I have code and based on that code I need to solve problem - JS

Tags: javascript

I am very beginner.

Based on this code

```
for (dwarfCounter; dwarfCounter <= 7; dwarfCounter++) {
    console.log('Krasnoludek #' + dwarfCounter + 'wciąż jest w domu, śpi twardo.');
}
```

This what I need:
We have 30 rabbits in very begining, than every 6 months we have double that number (60, 120...) and than for next 6 month we have triple that what we had in 6th month :) I have no Idea how to write the code.

Comment: I have no idea what that code has to do with the described problem.  More to the point, however, is that this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  We can certainly help with specific problems, but not knowing how to do your homework isn't a specific problem.  What you're looking for is either (1) introductory tutorials on JavaScript or (2) asking your instructor what the assignment is looking for.

Comment: I agree with @David. Google translates the text as follows:
Polish: Krasnoludek # wciąż jest w domu, śpi twardo
English: Dwarf # is still at home, sleeping soundly. Looks like something related to Snow White but feels like a spam post

Comment: How did this not get closed :P

Answer (score 0):

This works, but let me know if for(...) required.

```js
function count(a, b) {

var m = "month is";   if(b > 1) { m = "months" }

var time = b/6;

if(b < 6) { return "Only " + b + " " + m + " over D:" } else {
return b + " months are over, now we have " + a * (time*2) + " rabbits"; }
}

/// count(number of rabits, time in months)
document.write(count(30, 6))
```